# How to show a default value in a mat-select of a dynamic form?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I am updating a project to Angular 14 with Angular material, I have generated a generic form with several fields, but the mat-select does not keep the default option.

I am generating the dynamic FormControl from the component.ts, the text fields if the value is shown, but the mat-select is not.

This is my component.html:

```html
    <div  [formGroup]="formDialog" mat-dialog-content *ngFor="let column of data.columns">
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="column != 'province'">
            <input matInput [formControlName]="column" [placeholder]="column">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="column == 'province'">
            <mat-label>{{ column }}</mat-label>
            <mat-select [formControlName]="column" (valueChange)="currProvince($event)"> 
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of geoProvinces" [value]="item">
                    {{ item.nm }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

This is my component.ts:

```js
    ////////////
    this.data.dataRow = {
       "name":"test3Prov",
       "phoneNumber":123456,
       "province":"Madrid"
    }
    //////////////

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.getGeoAPI();

        let fieldControls = {};
        Object.entries(this.data.dataRow).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            fieldControls[key] = new FormControl(value || '');
        })
        this.formDialog = new FormGroup(fieldControls)
    }
```

This is the method where the provinces are obtained:

```js
    getGeoAPI(): void {
        this.genericService.getPath('geoApi').subscribe((elem: any) => {
          this.geoProvinces = elem.provinces
        })
      }
```

This is an example of `this.geoProvinces`:

```json
    [
       {
          "id":"01",
          "nm":"Álava"
       },
       {
          "id":"02",
          "nm":"Albacete"
       },
       {
          "id":"03",
          "nm":"Alicante"
       }
    ]
```

This is a screenshot with the form shown:

[image]

Comment: Is province just a simple string or an object? From your TS it looks like it is a string, from your HTML it looks like it is an object.

Comment: Sorry for yesterday I had to leave! Here you go, I posted a question to help you! :)

Comment: @manjirosano This component is a dialog that is displayed when editing a table row. `this.data.dataRow` is the object of the row to edit, in this case `province` is a String, and `geoProvinces` is the object that stores the list of provinces. What I want is that by default the province of the `dataRow` is selected, although I can change it

Comment: @build I ended up understanding it! I updated my answer, check it out! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your mat-select is feed with an array of object and your formControl value is an string

I imagine you can use in your mat-select as value "item.nm" (or what-ever property you has in your array)

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of geoProvinces" [value]="item.nm">
      {{ item.nm }}
</mat-option>
```

BTW if we can store an object we should use in the option [ngValue] instead [value]

Another option is that really you want to store in the formControl the "object", in this case you can add in your ngOnInit

```
Object.entries(this.data.dataRow).forEach(([key, value]) => {
     ...
})

this.formDialog = new FormGroup(fieldControls
const control=this.formDialog.get('province')
if (control && control.value)
{
   const province=this.geoProvinces.find(x=>x.nm==control.value)
   control.setValue(province?province:null)
}
```

**Update**

```
  //The array geoProvince is in the way 
     [{"id":"01","nm":"Álava"} ..]
  //And our data in the way 
     {"name":"test3Prov",
      "phoneNumber":123456,
      "province":"Madrid"
     }
```

So first we need think what we can store in the FormControl "province"

We can store the "name of the province"

```
const fieldControls: any = {};
Object.entries(this.data.dataRow).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    fieldControls[key] = new FormControl(value || '');
})
this.formDialog = new FormGroup(fieldControls)

//the ng-select like -see mat-option [value]="item.nm"
<mat-select [formControlName]="column"(selectionChange)="currProvince($event)"> 
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of geoProvinces" 
             [value]="item.nm">
            {{ item.nm }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

We can store the "id" of the province

```
const fieldControls: any = {};
Object.entries(this.data.dataRow).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    //we check if we are creating the formControl province
    //if true we asing the "id"
    if (key=="province"){
      const prov=this.geoProvinces.find(x=>x.nm==value)
      fieldControls[key] = new FormControl(prov?prov.id:null || '');
    }
    else
       fieldControls[key] = new FormControl(value || '');
})
this.formDialog = new FormGroup(fieldControls)

//the ng-select like -see mat-option [value]="item.id"
<mat-select [formControlName]="column"(selectionChange)="currProvince($event)"> 
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of geoProvinces" 
             [value]="item.id">
            {{ item.nm }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

We can store the whole object. We need take account that if we store an object or we asign the object (search in the array geoProvinces) or we using the property "compareWith"

Store the whole object search in the array geoProvinces

```
const fieldControls: any = {};
Object.entries(this.data.dataRow).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    //we check if we are creating the formControl province
    //if true we asing the element
    if (key=="province"){
      const prov=this.geoProvinces.find(x=>x.nm==value)
      fieldControls[key] = new FormControl(prov?prov:null || '');
    }
    else
       fieldControls[key] = new FormControl(value || '');
})
this.formDialog = new FormGroup(fieldControls)

//the ng-select like -see mat-option [value]="item"
<mat-select [formControlName]="column"(selectionChange)="currProvince($event)"> 
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of geoProvinces" 
             [value]="item">
            {{ item.nm }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Using "compareWith"

```
const fieldControls: any = {};
Object.entries(this.data.dataRow).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key=="province"){ //create "on-fly" and object"
       fieldControls[key] = new FormControl({nm:value || ''});
    else
      fieldControls[key] = new FormControl(value || '');
})
this.formDialog = new FormGroup(fieldControls)

//the ng-select like -see mat-option [value]="item"

//see also the [compareWith]="compareProvince"
<mat-select [formControlName]="column"
        [compareWith]="compareProvince"
        (selectionChange)="currProvince($event)"> 
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of geoProvinces" 
             [value]="item">
            {{ item.nm }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>

//and we declare compareProvince in .ts
compareProvince = (a: any, b: any) => a.nm == b.nm;
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqfxcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

Comment: I can't filter by the `geoProvinces` object it is filled in another method, in the onInit that object is empty. Anyway the value if it picks up, I'm doing the following, but it doesn't work: `this.formDialog.get('province').setValue(fieldControls['province'].value)`

Comment: how your geoProvinces array looks like? If e.g. is an array of object in the way [{id:..,nm:...}] you can use in options [value]="item.id" (until you don't fill geoProvinces, the select can not show anything)

Comment: I have updated the question, I have added the method where the provinces are obtained. In the `ngOnInit()`, `fieldControls['province'].value` contains the value of the `province`, which is the one I want to show by default

Comment: @build, you can use also async pipe, but the question is "how your geoProvinces array looks like"?

Comment: I just updated the question, I have added an array part of `this.geoProvinces`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do any of that, if you initially gave a value to your `formControlName`, I believe it should be displaying it.
Try changing `[formControlName]='column'` to `[formControlName]='province'`, this should work because you already gave it a value in your `.ts` file!

And don't use `valueChange()` use `selectionChange()`!

Comment: I downvote because each time you use in a mat-select formControlName and [value] or [(value)] a little cat die. The answer is give value to the formControl. NOTE: NOT use (valueChange) else (selectionChange)

Comment: I deleted my answer to this comment of yours, but I think it still is right. I thought I was saying dumb things but not really, he can always change the value of `selectedValue`, on `selectionChange()` but I still understand your point and you are right!
Having formControlName and value is stupid lol, pardon for my answer xD

Comment: @Eliseo  I deserved the downvote, I'll just quickly correct my answer, thanks for the correction! :)

Comment: True, the value of province is collected from what I have seen in the form. But still changing what you say I can't show the default value. I have also tried the following but it doesn't work: `this.formDialog.get('province').setValue(fieldControls['province'].value)`